# Weird PowerShell problem: [ref] cannot be applied to a variable that does not exist

Tags: powershell, pass-by-reference

My Powershell script exited with "[ref] cannot be applied to a variable that does not exist" after running a while (it actually worked for a while)

The code snippet is something like

```
function outputData(...) {
    $data = $null
    if ($outputQueue.TryTake([ref] $data, 1000) -eq $false) {
        continue
    }
    Write-Host $data
}
```

The detail errors thrown at the end are as below:

```
[ref] cannot be applied to a variable that does not exist.
At C:\Program Files\mfile.ps1:1213 char:13
+         if ($outputQueue.TryTake([ref] $data, 1000) -eq $ ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (data:VariablePath) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NonExistingVariableReference
```

May i ask if any thoughts about the cause ?

Thanks !

Comment: Thanks a lot. It runs in main thread and worked for several loops and then throws this error.

Comment: Note: The solution to the question _as asked_ is to simply ensure that `$data` _exists_ before casting it to `[ref]`, which `$data = $null` ensures.
The abstract phrase _it actually worked for a while_ in the question turned out to refer to a scenario where the variable _does exist_, yet _intermittent_ failures are seen, in a scenario involving _threads_.
This adds an interesting twist that is best explored in a _new_ question based on additional details. Based on the current form of this question, with its absence of creation of the `$data` variable, the answer given is a good fit.

Answer (score 2):

While error messages aren't always helpful, this one is:

It tells you that **the `$data` variable you're trying to use with `[ref]` must already *exist*, i.e., must have been *created explicitly***, which in PowerShell means:

- creating it by *assigning a value to it* - even if that value is  `$null`,
- or using `New-Variable` to create it.

A simplified example:

```
$data = $null # create variable $data

# OK to use $data with [ref], now that it exists.
# $data receives [int] value 10 in the process.
[int]::TryParse('10', [ref] $data)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Since the above function is executed in main thread. And at the top of the while loop, $data is assigned with $null value, isn't it automatically created as a new var ?

Comment: BTW, this issue is no always reproducible

Comment: @KenChen, yes, assigning `$null` should create it. In your question you didn't mention threading and having initialized the variable, so I suggest (a) creating a _new_ question that explains the threading scenario and shows the initialization,  ideally in the form of an [mcve] and (b) - given that we have a focused question with a focused answer here that may in itself be helpful to future readers - accept this answer.